# To count in how many list, certain elements appeared

Tags: python, list, loops

Several names that I want to count, in how many lists they appeared.

```
four_in_one = [['David','Ellen','Ken'],['Peter','Ellen','Joe'],['Palow','Ellen','Jack'],['Lily','Elain','Ken']]

for name in ['David','Ken','Kate']:
    for each_list in four_in_one:
        i = 0
        if name in each_list:
            i += 1
            print (name, i)
```

Output:

```
David 1
Ken 1
Ken 1
```

How can I output as below?

```
David 1
Kate 0
Ken 2
```

Comment: You reset the counter (`i = 0`) for each sub-list and you only print if the name is in that list

Comment: Think carefully about the logic of the code. How many times should `print (name, i)` happen, for a given name? Only once, or every time that it matches? Therefore, should that code be inside the `for each_list in four_in_one:` loop, or outside? Similarly, how many times should `i = 0` happen, and when?

Comment: As an aside, **please** try to practice some [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) skills. I'm assuming that these are simple logical problems that you should have no issue figuring out yourself - for the simple reason that I can see that you have asked about 300 Python questions at a fairly regular pace across the last 9 years. Assuming this is not a deliberate attempt to seed a canonical for a common logical error, please try to pay more attention to code before posting it here. If it was - the question could be much better framed.

Comment: I wonder Mark if you are not minded to hear feedback. It is all very well thanking "selfless helpers", but prior effort is not only a requirement here, but it is the only way you will improve as an engineer. Moreover, you appear to be wilfully ignoring edits that have been made on your questions for some years, and it is getting rather tiresome. Stack Overflow is a shared resource built by volunteers - **please see the downvotes and change course**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Move the counter declaration outside the inner loop.
- Print the result after the inner loop, rather than on each iteration of it.

```py
for name in ['David','Ken','Kate']:
    i = 0
    for each_list in four_in_one:
        if name in each_list:
            i += 1
    print(name, i)
```

The code can also be shortened using `sum`.

```py
i = sum(name in each_list for each_list in four_in_one)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let `Counter` do the counting on a flatten list, then limit the resulting object by the names you're looking for

```py
from collections import Counter

four_in_one = [['David','Ellen','Ken'],['Peter','Ellen','Joe'],['Palow','Ellen','Jack'],['Lily','Elain','Ken']]
names = ['David','Ken','Kate']

res = Counter([i for sublist in four_in_one for i in sublist])
res = {name: res[name] for name in names}

print(res)

# {'David': 1, 'Ken': 2, 'Kate': 0}
```

Comment: The question states *"in how many lists they appeared"* so if a name appears twice in the same list it might still be needed to be counted once, which will not happen with this solution...